# How to properly remove the contents inside of a modal

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The heights of each building from West (left) to East (right) is given in an integer array. You have to tell which buildings will be able to see the sunset. I've written a program that will be able to tell which buildings can view the sun from left to right. The problem I'm having is currently with the modal. I'm trying to clear the information that is inside the modal use `clearContents()`. At first, I was using `clear()` till i noticed that `clear()` is a global method. I then tried using `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = " ";`.

the entire website is provided but the code snippet is below.

https://zacharyhadjahsunsethills.netlify.app/

```js
let sunsetOrder = ["Building 1 will always view the sunset!"];


function BeginFunction(){
    //wire up all the data to the building variables
    let building1 = parseInt( document.getElementById("input1").value )
    let building2 = parseInt( document.getElementById("input2").value )
    let building3 = parseInt( document.getElementById("input3").value )
    let building4 = parseInt( document.getElementById("input4").value )
    let building5 = parseInt( document.getElementById("input5").value )


    //User Input validation
    if(building1 == null || building2 == null || building3 == null || building4 == null || 
        building5 == null){
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `You must input numbers for all buildings`
         //clear data
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ``
    }else{
        //Put all the buildings into an array
        let buildingsArray = [building1, building2, building3, building4, building5]

        //You will need to use  nested for loops. Nested for loops are how you can properly
        //compare elements inside of an array with eachother.

        //Loop starts at one because it will be the loop that is compared to all the 
        //previous buildings that are infront of it  
        for (let currentBuilding = 1; currentBuilding < buildingsArray.length; currentBuilding++) {

            //will be kept false UNTIL you find the tallest building
            //once tallest building is found, it will be switched to true
            let tallest = false;
    
            //this loop starts at one because it will need to stay before the position of the 
            //current building. It needs to stay before current building to properly compare
            //which building is taller. That is why the middle condition is 
            // previousBuilding < currentBuilding
            for (let previousBuilding = 0; previousBuilding < currentBuilding; previousBuilding++) {
                
                //if any of the previous building are taller than the building that is currently being compared with,
                //then change the bool to true  
                if(buildingsArray[previousBuilding] >= buildingsArray[currentBuilding]){
                    tallest = true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }        

            if(tallest == false){
                sunsetOrder.push("Building #" +(currentBuilding + 1)+ " can view the sunset")
            }
            else{
                sunsetOrder.push("Building #" +(currentBuilding + 1)+ " can't view the sunset")
            }

            let results = sunsetOrder.join("<br>")
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `${results}`
        }
    }
}


function clearContents(){
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML ="";
}
```

```css
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link{
    color:white;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    color:black;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand{
    color:black;
}

.container {
    width:960px;
    height:640px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-320px;
    margin-left:-480px;
}

body{
    background-image: url("img/SunsetHillsBackground.png");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

::selection{
    background-color: #F0E440;
}

#ResultsHeader{
    background-color: #F0E440;
}

#ResultsFooter{
    background-color: #F0E440;
}

#ResultsBody{
    background-color:#f3eb7b
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Fizz Buzz Coding Challenge (Implementing the Meta Strat</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prism.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" style="background-color:  #F0E440;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SunsetHills</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="solve.html">Solve <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="code.html">☀Code</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="https://zacharyhadjah.netlify.app/">Portfolio</a>
                </li>      
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/zhadjah9559/SunsetHills">Github</a>
                </li>      
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container pt-5 align-items-center">       

        <div class="row justify-content-center pb-4">
            <img src="img/SunsetHills.png" alt="Sunset Hills logo" id="Logo" class="responsive" >
        </div>
        <hr/>

        <div class="row pt-5 mt-5">
            <div class="col-md form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Enter Height" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Enter Height" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="input3" placeholder="Enter Height" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="input4" placeholder="Enter Height" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="input5" placeholder="Enter Height" type="number"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row justify-content-center pt-2">
            <label>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="BeginFunction()"
                          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ResultsModal">
                          Submit
                </button>
            </label>
        </div>

        
    </div>

  
       <!--Results Modal-->
      <div class="modal fade" id="ResultsModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header justify-content-center" id="ResultsHeader">    
                <h1 id="ResultsHeaderH1">Results</h1>
              </div> 
              
              <div class="modal-body" id="ResultsBody">
                <div id="small-dialog2" class="white-popup zoom-anim-dialog text-center">
                  
                      <div id=results></div>
                      
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center" id="ResultsFooter">
                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="clearContents()">Close</button>  
                
              </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Results Modal-->
    </div>    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/prism.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about ```elem.style.display = "none"```? You can change the ```innerHTML```s for the next batch of info and then redisplay it.

Comment: Gave a shot but when I tried calculating again, the results would not show back up, even when i did `elem.style.display = "display"` after hiding.

Comment: @Xenosphere You should use `elem.style.display = ""`.

Comment: I see it working as you describe - what am I missing? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxwy6.png

Comment: user enters 1,2,3,4,5 the first Time. The answers will be displayed. The user then hits the close button. NEXT, when the user enters 9,6,5,4,3 the results will not be displayed. I'm trying to get the program to a point in which the results will be cleared when the close button is hit, and the next set of results will be entered in when the user hits the submit button again

Comment: ```elem.style.display = initial```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the content of the web with the devs tools you can see that your function `clearContents()` is working correctly.

The problem here is that you ain't clearing your sunsetOrder array, so every time that you do click on the submit button you are pushing new elements to it and showing all the array in the modal.

To solve this you can add the following code to your clearContents function:

```
function clearContents() {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML ="";
    sunsetOrder = [];
}
```